# What this “resp.” means?

Tags: analysis, notation, terminology

I’m not a native English speaker and not a good math reader too.
My question came while I reading this Debreu article about a existence of a real function to represent the preferences and I’m stuck in this passage:

> If $A$, $B$ are two $f$-sets (resp. $i$-sets) and $A \cap B$ is not empty, then $A \cup B$ is an $f$-set (resp. $i$-set).

What’s this “resp.” means?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  It means *respectively*

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: See also the entry for "resp." in [the descriptive informalities section of the English Wikipedia page listing mathematical jargon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_jargon#Descriptive_informalities).

Comment: Phrased in words, the statement is: “The classes of both $i$- and $f$-sets are closed under intersections of non-disjoint sets”.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It abbreviates the word *respectively*. In this context it means that two results are being stated simultaneously:

- if $A,B$ are two $f$-sets, and $A\cap B\ne\varnothing$, then $A\cup B$ is an $f$-set; and
- if $A,B$ are two $i$-sets, and $A\cap B\ne\varnothing$, then $A\cup B$ is an $i$-set.

In other words, read it first without the parenthetical items, and then read it again with the parenthetical items substituted for the items immediately before them.

Answer (score 6):

Resp. is an abbreviation for respectively.

What was written there is a shorter way of saying the following.

> If $A,B$ are two f-sets and $A\cap B$ is not empty, then $A\cup B$ is an f-set.

> If $A,B$ are two i-sets and $A\cap B$ is not empty, then $A\cup B$ is an i-set.